# Picasso: Failed to Delete when navigating away from activity

Tags: android, picasso

EDIT: I just started getting these crashes just as a new image is trying to load on the first activity that uses Picasso, so Picasso's image management seems to be working fine. I noticed this isn't happening but on the Nexus 5. My HTC One running 4.4.2 doesn't have this issue. It also stops for a short while after clearing the cache.

<strike>From what I understand, Picasso is supposed to handle everything for you. There's some examples of how to cancel requests but they are few and far apart. That said, I am having an issue where if an activity with an adapter that loads images is navigated away from while the image is still loading, OkHttp throws an IOException:</strike>

```
03-10 17:13:08.972  21440-21626/[Package] E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: OkHttp DiskLruCache
    Process: [Package], PID: 21440
    java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: failed to delete /data/data/[Package]/cache/picasso-cache/7e2da32a20d0abcdb2ae7347580c9658.0
            at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.DiskLruCache$1.run(DiskLruCache.java:175)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
     Caused by: java.io.IOException: failed to delete /data/data/[Package]/cache/picasso-cache/7e2da32a20d0abcdb2ae7347580c9658.0
            at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.DiskLruCache.remove(DiskLruCache.java:584)
            at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.DiskLruCache.trimToSize(DiskLruCache.java:639)
            at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.DiskLruCache.access$100(DiskLruCache.java:86)
            at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.DiskLruCache$1.run(DiskLruCache.java:169)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Any ideas?